# Cannot send mail in SharePoint using Event Receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint, events, email

I have a Web Part in SharePoint 2010 that has an Event Receiver that fires when an item is added to a list. The Event Receiver is supposed to send a mail but does not.

It works fine when I try without the Event Receiver, how can I send mail using an Event Receiver?

```
StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();
string body = "Hi!";
headers.Add("to", "paulo@paulo.se");
headers.Add("from", "paulosaysno@paulo.se");
headers.Add("subject", "Paulo says hi");
headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body)
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or are there are errors in the SharePoint ULS logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And event receiver runs in the context of an HTTP request. It is known that SPUtility.SendEmail has issues with this. A common practice is to set HttpContext.Current to null while sending the email:

```
SPWeb thisWeb = thisSite.RootWeb;
string toField = "someone@microsoft.com";
string subject = "Test Message";
string body = "Message sent from SharePoint";
HttpContext oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
HttpContext.Current = null;

bool success = SPUtility.SendEmail(thisWeb, true, true, toField, subject, body);
HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
```

Reference (scroll down to the comments): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but it does not solve the problem. Are there anymore issues regarding Event Receivers and sending mail in SharePoint?